# passing Illegal Token to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I'm trying to pass a variable that looks like `68679786987698_987687697869786` to a function in Javascipt, but I'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in Chrome's developer console. It looks like the underscore is the problem, but I need it to stay there. Any suggestions?

Here's the relevant code:

```
entry += '<span><a href="javascript:likePost(' + post.id + ');">Like</a>';

function likePost(id) {
    alert('like');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how line 1 relates to the rest of the code. What are you doing with `entry`, and where are you calling `likePost` from? Are you only getting the error when you click the `<a>` element?

Comment: `entry` gets appended into the DOM. The error only comes when clicking on the `<a>` element

`likePost` gets called later on. It's in the right place

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes:

`entry += '<span><a href="javascript:likePost(\'' + post.id + '\');">Like</a>';`

post.id must be a string if it contains the underscore.